# How do I perform const_cast in this case correctly?

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
static bool Validate(const char& letter, string& aWord)
```

I need to invoke it

```
Validate(letter, aWord); // where aWord is const
```

What is the correct way to const_cast in this case?

Comment: The correct way is **NOT** to cast it. The signature here is saying that Validate() may alter the parameter `aWord`. Thus passing it a const value that is going to be mutated is undefined behavior. The correct solution is to change Validate so that it takes `aWord` as a const.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that the function does not modify the string, you can do this:

```
Validate (letter, const_cast<std::string &>(aWord));
```

However, a safer thing to do, albeit it an unnecessary copy if the signature could hypothetically be changed to `const`, would be to copy the string and pass the copy.

```
std::string copyOfAWord = aWord;
Validate (letter, copyOfAWord);
```

If it does change something, your copy would have the results instead, but it would break your logic in the first place.

Comment: Getting an error : const_cast must contain pointer, reference, or a pointer to member to an object.

Comment: @kunj2aan, oops, sorry. The cast was missing an ampersand.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is **NOT** to cast it.

The signature here

```
static bool Validate(const char& letter, string& aWord)
```

is saying that `Validate()` may alter the parameter `aWord`. Thus passing it a const value that is going to be mutated is undefined behavior (if it is mutated (see last paragraph)).

If you are **sure** that `Validate()` does not mutate `aWord` then **Still Dont** cast away constness. In this case change its signature to reflect the guarantees provided.

The fact that `aWord` is not const means the it could mutate `aWord`. Even if it does not mutate in this version, somebody in the future may come along and change that. Then your program will break in such a horrible way that it will be imposable to find the error.

If you are casting away constness then you are doing something wrong.

The only solution (if you can;t change the interface) here is to pass a non cost version. Since you don;t have one you should create one:

```
std::string    aWordTmpCopy(aWord);
Validate(letter, aWordTmpCopy);
```